# how to create different instances of the database created using scaffold in rails application for different users?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

I am new to ruby on rails and I am working on a project wherein the system would generate reports based on the GUI like pie charts, bar charts etc , based on the data imported from the excel/csv file in the database. The application consists of number of different users who would be able to generate their reports.
However I am not able to find out how I will create different instances of the database for different users so that it every user gets a blank database at first and then they can upload their content to it.
If someone can guide me through, it would be really helpful!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all... do you really think you need a completely blank database for every user? It can sure be done using something like the `apartment` gem with users as tennants, but it seems a bit overhead. 
Would the structure of the database be different for each user, or would just the data be different?

Comment: @Almaron.   yes the data would be different for every user however the schema of database would be the same .

Comment: If the schema would be the same, why don't you just add a user_id scope on the key tables?